# Convert CSV file to JSON file using PowerShell ignore scientific notation

Tags: powershell, import-csv, convertto-json

I have .csv files containing long numbers. I used the following PowerShell script to convert from `.csv` file to `.json`. But the long numbers are importing as scientific notation.

How to force import long number from csv to json without converting to scientific notation?

Here is my PowerShell script,

```
import-csv -path "F:\DATA_002.csv" -UseCulture | select "Name", "Mobile", "Other mobile no." | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "F:\DATA_002.json"
```

Comment: "Name","Mobile","Other mobile no."
"John","7981628561","9.18E+11"

Comment: It looks like the problem is with how the csv file is being generated in the first place, rather than anything to do with ```Import-Csv``` or ```ConvertTo- Json```. If the csv file contains scientific notation to 2 decimal places you’re not going to be able to recreate the missing digits of the phone number from the csv alone…

Comment: You can try `Import-Csv "F:\DATA_002.csv" -UseCulture | ForEach-Object { $_."Other mobile no." = $_."Other mobile no." -as [long]; $_ } | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "F:\DATA_002.json"`  or `Import-Csv "F:\DATA_002.csv" -UseCulture | Select-Object Name, Mobile, @{n = 'Other'; e = { $_."Other mobile no." -as [long] } } | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "F:\DATA_002.json"`

Comment: Works great. Can you post it as answer. I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) astutely pointed out in a comment, you may not be able to get the original number back however if you just want to get rid of the scientific notation you can try either of the following:

```
Import-Csv "F:\DATA_002.csv" -UseCulture | 
    ForEach-Object { $_."Other mobile no." = $_."Other mobile no." -as [long]; $_ } | 
        ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "F:\DATA_002.json"
```

```
Import-Csv "F:\DATA_002.csv" -UseCulture | 
    Select-Object Name, Mobile, @{n = 'Other'; e = { $_."Other mobile no." -as [long] } } | 
        ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "F:\DATA_002.json"
```

Both use converting the scientific notation text to a [long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.2#423-integer) object type using the [`-as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) operator.

A word of caution when using the `-as` operator.  If the conversion fails, it will do so silently and the output will be null.  If you'd rather it fail with notification, try casting the value to long rather than using `-as`

```
[long]$_."Other mobile no."
```